# How to do substring in hive when the string length is not known

Tags: hive, substring

I'm trying to do a substring on a column to derive a value.

My values in the column can be like: 
**`(abcde), (qweryjj), (yehehsb)`**.

I need to eliminate the brackets and just provide the values in the output So,
I tried this:

```
substring(string,2,(length(string)))
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to eliminate the brackets from the column value then use

```
regexp_replace(string column_name, string pattern, string replacement_string)
```

on the column.For example the below expression replaces '(' or ')' from the string "(abcde)" with ""

```
regexp_replace("(abcde)", "(|)", "") returns abcde
```

So in your select statement you would use the column name like this below

```
select regexp_replace(column_name,  "(|)", "") from table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.Actually the bigger scenario is

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TRANSLATE` function.

```
select TRANSLATE ( column_name,  '()', '') from yourtable;
```